# How to include Oxford Comma in Chicago.bst for more than two authors?

Tags: bibliographies, natbib, punctuation, chicago-style

```
FUNCTION {format.lab.names}
  { 's :=
s num.names$ 'numnames :=
numnames #4 >    % change number to number of others allowed before
       % forcing "et al".
{ s #1 "{vv~}{ll}" format.name$ " et~al." * }
{
  numnames #1 - 'namesleft :=
  #2 'nameptr :=
  s #1 "{vv~}{ll}" format.name$
{ namesleft #0 > }
{ nameptr numnames =
    { s nameptr "{ff }{vv }{ll}{ jj}" format.name$ "others" =
    { " et~al." * }
    { " and " * s nameptr "{vv~}{ll}" format.name$ * }
      if$
    }
    { ", " * s nameptr "{vv~}{ll}" format.name$ * }
  if$
  nameptr #1 + 'nameptr :=
  namesleft #1 - 'namesleft :=
}
  while$
}
 if$
}
```

Answer (score 2):

(too long for a comment, hence posted as an answer)

Your query is a bit confusing. Based on the title of your query, which includes "chicago.bst", and the fact that you set the tag `natbib`, I will assume that you're using BibTeX and the `natbib` citation management package. Now, the BibTeX bibliography style called `chicago` -- which, by the way, is rather ancient and hence does *not* implement the formatting guidelines of the *current* edition of the "University of Chicago Manual of Style" (aka "Chicago") -- does in fact use the "Oxford comma". This is true for the formatted entries in the bibliography and -- if `natbib` was loaded with the `longnamesfirst` option -- the citation call-outs.

If you are not using `chicago.bst` and `natbib`, but rather `biblatex-chicago` and `biber`, you'll still get the "Oxford comma" by default. (To get truncated first and middle names, you'll have to load the `biblatex-chicago` package with the option `firstinits`, i.e., `\usepackage[firstinits]{biblatex-chicago}`.)

Hence, do please clarify what you're trying to achieve.

---

Here's a short sample document that verifies the assertions I made above for the `chicago`/`natbib` case. (It holds for `biblatex-chicago` and `biber` too.) I've highlighted all four instances of the "Oxford comma" -- two in the citation call-outs and two in the bibliography.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{mybib.bib}
@misc{a:3001,
  author={Adam Alan Alonzo},
  title ={What?},
  year  =3001,
}
@misc{ab:3002,
  author={Adam Alan Alonzo and Brenda Bettina Black},
  title ={When?},
  year  =3002,
}
@misc{abc:3003,
  author={Adam Alan Alonzo and Brenda Bettina Black and Carla Christina Color},
  title ={Who?},
  year  =3003,
}
@misc{abcw:3004,
  author={Adam Alan Alonzo and Brenda Bettina Black and Carla Christina Color and William Walter White},
  title ={Why?},
  year  =3004,
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[authoryear,round,longnamesfirst]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{chicago}

\begin{document}
\citep{a:3001,ab:3002,abc:3003,abcw:3004}, \citet{abcw:3004}.
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```